# Multidimensional array with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Guys I'm trying to solve a programming problem.
I have to generate a two-dimensional array containing blocks represented by colors.

The final result I want to achieve is this:

```
[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
[2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[3,6,5,5,6,5,5,3]
[3,6,6,5,5,6,6,3]


4: purple, occupies an entire line.
2: red, occupies two spaces on each line.
1: black occupies 6 spaces
3: orange, occupies 1 space of each line
6: blue, occupies 1 space
5: green occupies two line spaces
```

Can anybody help me?
The code I'm trying to do is this:

```
let purple = [[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]];
let red = [[2, 2], [2, 2]];
let black = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
let orange = [[3], [3]];
let blue = [[6]];
let green = [[5, 5]];

let elements = [purple, red, black, orange, blue, green];

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i])
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let purple = [
  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
];
let red = [
  [2, 2],
  [2, 2]
];
let black = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];
let orange = [
  [3],
  [3]
];
let blue = [
  [6]
];
let green = [
  [5, 5]
];

let elements = [purple, red, black, orange, blue, green];
let grid = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  jloop: for (let j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
    yloop: for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {
        if (grid[y][x]) continue;
        let space_on_this_line = grid[y].length - x;
        if (elements[i].length <= space_on_this_line) {
          for (let k = 0; k < elements[i][j].length; k++) {
            grid[y][x + k] = elements[i][j][k];
          }
          if (++j>=elements[i].length) break jloop;
          continue yloop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
  console.log(grid[y].join(""));
}
```

something like this, right?